# Pytorch saving model UserWarning: Couldn't retrieve source code for container of type Network

Tags: python, save, warnings, pytorch

When saving model in Pytorch by using:

```
torch.save(model, 'checkpoint.pth')
```

I get the following warning:

> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py:193:
>   UserWarning: Couldn't retrieve source code for container of type
>   Network. It won't be checked for correctness upon loading.   "type " +
>   obj.**name** + ". It won't be checked "

When I load it I get the following error:

```
state_dict = torch.load('checkpoint_state_dict.pth')
model = torch.load('checkpoint.pth')
model.load_state_dict(state_dict)


AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6a79854aef0f> in <module>()
      2 state_dict = torch.load('checkpoint_state_dict.pth')
      3 model = 0
----> 4 model = torch.load('checkpoint.pth')
      5 model.load_state_dict(state_dict)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
    301         f = open(f, 'rb')
    302     try:
--> 303         return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
    304     finally:
    305         if new_fd:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in _load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
    467     unpickler = pickle_module.Unpickler(f)
    468     unpickler.persistent_load = persistent_load
--> 469     result = unpickler.load()
    470 
    471     deserialized_storage_keys = pickle_module.load(f)

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Network' on <module '__main__'>
```

Why is not possible to save a model and reload it entirely?

Comment: it seems pytorch can't find your definition for the NN model.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Saving

```
torch.save({'state_dict': model.state_dict()}, 'checkpoint.pth.tar')
```

Loading

```
model = describe_model()
checkpoint = torch.load('checkpoint.pth.tar')
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
```

Comment: Thank you but where can I find describe_model() ?

Comment: @DarioFederici This is your model. You defined this in the code before training. You need to define again the model to load checkpoint to your model.

Comment: OK so describe_model() is the NN definition.

Comment: @DarioFederici . Yes your neural network, first define the model, then upload weights into it.

Comment: executing the above code "torch.save({'state_dict': model.state_dict()},...)" returned TypeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable.

Comment: why the original got warnings?